# CollectionView not displaying last section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom UICollectionView that has a total of 4 (0, 1, 2, 3) sections. What I am doing is that if there is no info to display the `section 2`, then I am setting the cell sizes for this section to `CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 0)`. The problem is that the cells from section 3 then don't get displayed either, even thought `CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 50)` gets called on on `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` in my switch for `section 3`.

What I discovered so far is that my `switch` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` with `case 2 and 3` doesnt get called in this case.

What I have also discovered is that setting `section 2` to `return 0` cells shows `section 3`.

What I think I am missing is something in the `layout` that I am doing wrong ... maybe one of you has encountered this before.

Here is some of my code.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 50)
    case 1: return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 75)
    case 2:
        if let description = description , description.characters.count > 0 {
            let sizingNibNew = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BioCollectionViewCell", owner: BioCollectionViewCell.self, options: nil)
            let sizingCellNew = sizingNibNew?[0] as! BioCollectionViewCell

                sizingCellNew.myText = description

            sizingCellNew.initialize()

            return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: sizingCellNew.myTextView.frame.height + 10)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 0)
        }
    case 3:
        return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 50)
    default:
        return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 0)
    }
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0: return 4
    case 1: return 1
    case 2: return 1
    case 3: return 2
    default:
        return 0
    }
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 0:
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0: 
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MapView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MapView

            if let address = address, let city = city {
                cell.setAddressInMapView(address, cityAddress: city)
            }

            return cell
        case 1: 
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TitleCell

            cell.titleLabel.text = title1

            return cell

        case 2: 
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NameCell

            cell.nameLabel.text = xName

            return cell
        case 3: // address
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AddressCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddressCell

            cell.addressLabel.text = address

            return cell
        default:
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

    case 1:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Name", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShowFeaturedArtist

        cell.xId = id ?? ""
        cell.nameLabel.text = name ?? ""

        cell.populateViewWithoutQuery()

        return cell

    case 2:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BioCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BioCollectionViewCell

        if let description = description where description.characters.count > 0 {
            cell.myText = description
        }
        cell.initialize()

        return cell

    case 3:
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("UserAttending", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserAttending

            cell.label.text = "0 " + " Users Attending"
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("UserAttending", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserAttending

            cell.label.text = "Release Dates"
            return cell

        default:
            return UICollectionViewCell()

        }

    default:
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Issue?? In `section-2` you have no data to display so you put the height as 0 and your `cellAtItem`dost not call thats ok. If you put the `height = 0` then what you expecting the complier........ to execute the `cellForItem` for wasting the CPU cycles.

Comment: the problem is that if `section 2` has no data `section 3` is not displayed

Comment: Make your data source in such a way that section 3 comes to section 2 and reload collection view

Comment: Something like if [array1,0,aray3] make it like [array1,array3] and reload data

Comment: dont do calculations in sizeForItem it will reduce scroll performance

Comment: reloading data is not a good idea, will basically cause the collectionView to render again

Comment: @John Reloading data doest make conflicts. So whenever you have new data and wanted to load in CollectionView then what you like to do?

Comment: BUT I DON*T HAVE NEW DATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by doing this in `numberOfItemsInSection`:

```
switch section {
    case 0: return 6
    case 1: return 1
    case 2:
        if show._description?.characters.count > 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    case 3: return 2
```

Comment: Exactly. What  you need to do.

Comment: true, but also having items with size 0 in a section should not affect other sections

Comment: My different custom header for each section was not showing. I had two sections, But I didn't specify the `numberOfItemsInSection`. After  giving numberOfItemsInSection for each section, The header shows up. Thanks! Your answer helped my indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want to show a section, int `numberOfItemsInSection` methods, for a your discriminant(no item to display) should return 0(zero) for that section, and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will never called for that section.

The change of the heigth of the cell is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` method to `return 4` only if there is data to display in the second section, else to `return 3`?

In this way you wouldn't need to change the height of your cells, which isn't a good way to go anyway.